# Simple limit of a sequence with triple logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is not a homework! :) Just preparing for exam.

How can I calculate the following limit of a sequence?

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \left[4\log(2\text{n})-\log\left(\frac{2\text{n}^2 - 1}{3}\right) - \log(3n^2-1)\right]$$

Should I first take into account only the first two components (dividing logarithms) and then take into account the final component (divide logarithms again)?

The kind of funny thing is that I can easily solve sort of more complex limits and simpler limits, I'm specifically struggling with this one (and other logarithmic limits).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\small 4\log(2\text{n})-\log\left(\frac{2\text{n}^2 - 1}{3}\right) - \log(3n^2-1) = \log(16n^{4}) - \log(2n^2-1) - \log(3n^2-1) +\log(3)}$$
and so
$${\small 4\log(2\text{n})-\log\left(\frac{2\text{n}^2 - 1}{3}\right) - \log(3n^2-1) = \log\left(\frac{16n^4}{(2n^2-1)(3n^2-1)}\right)+\log(3)}$$

Answer (score 2):

As usual, there are many ways to do it.

Remember that $n$ is large; so
$$4\log(2{n})-\log\left(\frac{2{n}^2 - 1}{3}\right) - \log(3n^2-1)\simeq 4\log(2{n})-\log\left(\frac{2{n}^2}{3}\right) - \log(3n^2)$$ Now, either combine the logarithms as Lucas Corrêa did or just expand them as
$$4 \log(2)+4\log(n)-\log(2)-2\log(n)+\log(3)-\log(3)-2\log(n)$$ and simplify.